# Apache2 ModRewrite rule to remove trailing character in a query param

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

This should be fairly straightforward but I'm having a lot of trouble.

**Goal:** If the "name" query param has a trailing colon, remove it:

```
https://example.com/dir/?foo=bar&name=hello:&baz=bat#123  ==>
https://example.com/dir/?foo=bar&name=hello&baz=bat#123
```

I've tried a BUNCH of rules and haven't found one that works. The closest I've come is:

```
# Grab "name" value w/out trailing colon
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*[?&]*)name=(.*):(.*)
# Duplicate original path and add query parameters
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1name=%2%3 [L,R=302]
```

This almost works, **except it redirects to the top-level directory:**

```
https://example.com/dir/?foo=bar&name=hello:&baz=bat#123  ==>
https://example.com/?foo=bar&name=hello&baz=bat#123
```

I want this rewrite to work for the top-level domain name or **any** number of subdirectories. How can I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you using this `.htaccess` file? Can you have any number of other URL parameters? In any order?

Comment: _"except it redirects to the top-level directory"_ - can't see how that would be the case with just the rule you have shown - you are explicitly matching the full URL path there, and are inserting it into the substitution URL again as `$1`. You probably have more rewriting in there than just the bit you have shown us, and something else interferes.

Comment: @CBroe That will happen if the `.htaccess` file is not in the root directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> (.*[?&]*)name=(.*):(.*)
> ```

This regex doesn't just match a trailing colon at the end of the `name` URL parameter value, it matches `name=` followed by `:` anywhere in the query string (including in the middle of or as part of other URL parameters). It also matches any URL parameter name that simply ends with `name`, eg. `fooname=hello&bar=ba:z`.

The missing subdirectories would seem to suggest you are using this rule in a `.htaccess` file in the `/dir` subdirectory (as opposed to the root)? The `RewriteRule` *pattern* (which you are capturing) only matches the URL-path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

Note that the fragment identifier (the `#123` part) is not sent to the server - this is managed entirely by the browser.

Depending on the URL parameter values you are expecting, you may need the `NE` (`noescape`) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive to prevent the resulting values being doubly URL-encoded in the redirect response. This is because the `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not %-decoded and the resulting substitution string is %-encoded by default before sending this back to the client.

Try the following instead:

```
# Grab "name" value w/out trailing colon
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+&)?(name=[^&]*):(&.+)?$
# Duplicate original path and add query parameters
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2%3 [NE,R=302,L]
```

Needless to say, this needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, before any existing (internal) rewrites.

I included the `name=` part in the capturing subpattern. Any URL parameters before or after the `name` URL param are entirely optional. Only colons at the end of the `name` URL parameter value are removed.

The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the root-relative URL-path (including the slash prefix), so this works to preserve the URL-path, regardless of where the `.htaccess` file is located.

Comment: Yo Mister White! Thanks, the key issue was I'd forgotten that the `RewriteRule` pattern matched the path relative to the `.htaccess` directory. I knew my regex wasn't ideal but I wanted to keep it simple for this question. It probably would've taken me a lot longer to get it right than it took you, so thanks for that too! (Still seems weird to me that without `${REQUEST_URI}` or prefixing with `/` it redirects to the full pathname of the file on disk, but that's fine.)

Comment: @mgiuffrida "Still seems weird ... it redirects to the full pathname of the file on disk" - if the resulting _substitution_ is _relative_ then the directory-prefix (the abs file-path of the `.htaccess` file) is added back. This is desirable for internal rewrites (URL rewriting) - which is the majority of use cases - just not for external redirects. (You could also make use of `RewriteBase`.)